# Iterating a list in a rule

Tags: list, variables, prolog, rules

The following is in a file called couples.pl

```
likes(X,Y).
likes(Y,X).
couple(X,Y):-
    likes(X,Y),
    likes(Y,X).
%
docouple(X|[]).
docouple(X|[H|T]) :- 
   likes(X,H),
   likes(H,X),
   couple(X,H),
   write(X),
   write(' and '),
   write(H),
   writeln(' are a couple'), 
   docouple(X|T).
```

The rule iterates through the list if I type this at the ?- prompt:

```
docouple('jim'|['helena','nicole','mia','giada']).
```

I need to know how to represent the list as a variable for a list on another line, or a list in a separate .pl file.

Comment: Looks like confusion between lists and rules. Can use e.g. https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=foreach/2 and https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=foreach//3 , or e.g. https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=setof/3 to get a list - what exactly do you want to accomplish?